# Are there occurrances of monel (nickel-copper) meteorite materials?

Tags: asteroid, meteorites, minerals

This question is prompted by a [Space.com article](https://www.space.com/psyche-metal-asteroid-composition) on the metallic Psyche asteroid -

> Wendy Caldwell, a scientist at Los Alamos National Laboratory, told
> Space.com that some of her most promising results, including the
> findings of a 2020 study, had the asteroid being made of Monel, a
> metal that is made mainly of nickel and copper and is thought to be
> representative of the composition of metallic objects in space.

- and makes reference to ["Understanding Asteroid 16 Psyche’s Composition through 3D
  Impact Crater Modeling", Caldwell et al.](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272593/1-s2.0-S0019103520X00133/1-s2.0-S0019103520303304/am.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEMf%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIE6QHTxGiSvMSpiVW%2B%2BFLrESjM77g0yKSCDu7DcLSOO7AiBrYPnalX80b8kqbYS2OKTMCGi96ZB7CV58Rv3gu1RqaSq7BQjg%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAUaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIM9gxJy4YVcCnXkkcQKo8FkugLO18ic2aW8vW5S6OFoX0d5X%2B7isOIW8AS95MhF6gHoMR%2B1oDYg0IfNnFYYDCz0MeqYH7T4ObrsKNeE5BOyzJ07BckuMXLnt69sV4ZydyCbfrUyLBSSymAJyvfqVLB%2B5nBWfn%2FWIzArCFixE42nE2tRS0M643mVvNs8Y6sswGWN8eTPUd5U3N57Z37NZIzsLz9tmccYUoHOkTzyjZvvpPLUSgkhJ0nCaPY7RPT1djdnRjnYQywgpRz6G4X9omrBAOphflRk%2BYf06IIwaH%2B2BREQnVTNq5irOLAukznHYI94QIZ2EcjpgZ7tEKalDJBbIFhiZs87Q0MVzy4fzqmrWp%2B4SFLPH7h0uqJ3cFDRABhN0mlc0OwWAjDd3cWdoMEq08tBclPJ0YFsPa4sqVtWx6fvGiRMF3dykv%2FTdddeUrZtFE2wZkVgMuVhfkdmOwqIcMt4MwtzD9Ps1nxsSd5krdsuzCjk%2BtS1YHYnOSJHgNfN2R2l6Lfg7xsnPMDIuTp%2Bi7%2B92XApBCSYpvsyyNPLdy23Uh93TuJQzFr5fRTD7xcmgOe3wfFpKaNIjs3pzZZd09dGogv82qOal4j%2FbKJkoZURqY4jyoMRjypgUl52P80Awaaq7jh%2B32CNYHlPQqRKJ2AV%2BvOko7h6iXIEBtBKusnfBdOVUHvhcBoFiMXfKh5JlSt9QS1fp6tpDjQp1ZJzp%2BrYZCXf9Stb9v4wtu9ZzATrgEuBzZtzM4zKzLyU9o7Eq%2BS8bYNQFpK7KgV%2FTBhEmHmQPAWhkxJS8xEtLT6tTDQXUrpKfEfWx1hGlxeXqior7KjiEb97Xdgn5QOxLmdBiKpwDxUwsV2lMhoRSgE7N9cJCD1d0lqnB4Oqam5CDDC%2FsupBjqyAVPrnq6sOlEBVsuwRp%2F0c%2Bay6cSrl%2B89YK2Ni7WrAKG%2BEdB0f4oKno%2F9yvWYN1vYJO4j0a9O%2BqhM51tDC8c%2BbMZJVmlN7UUY8RPTMmoNZIAONa2S%2B5lJK84SgEMwdi6eeLGuySC1VFSHvWiQWCR2QGpUX2ExrjthWQKc3sbVy5TUPRPRqP1CgRN2SKFVBqMZixUWDC2tbNBd0dUvJJpl9opPEr9sb4gIYD67ZgMcntwlBEM%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20231020T230059Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY7PVFSSF7%2F20231020%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=d962c69503f01c4d12428388861bfa61afee1b8c0d195ff4b9b90549e33fe6b8&hash=623f3760ad123148ded3a9d207041b9dbb60ebc94ec4eef79abb03ba86f830b4&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0019103520303304&tid=pdf-af9559a9-1f89-4246-be28-b394842861e3&sid=cd3f1387314fe841441a66920ebccba74577gxrqa&type=client)

I had the clear impression nickel-iron - *not* nickel-copper - is considered representative of the composition of metallic asteroid material. The presence of nickel-copper (monel) appears based on minerals found at Sudbury Basin, Canada - "a large impact structure".

Whilst meteorite samples tested won't include every possible mineral I would expect to find examples of *monel* meteorite material if it were "representative". Are there any such examples?

Comment: Are you interesting in just monel or cupronickel as well? Cupronickel has less than 60% copper.

Comment: @Fred - Caldwell said monel, but any metallic meteorite material that is NOT mostly nickel-iron with concentrations within the range of the primary minerals taenite and kamecite would be unusual and interesting. More interesting again if they exist on their own than just as differentiated crystals within bulk nickel-iron (ie formed during solidification - can't think the name of that process).

Comment: On Earth, it's not unusual for find copper &/or cobalt in nickel deposits. Given the densities of Ni, Cu & Co are 8.908, 8.960 & 8.900 g/cm3 respectively & their element numbers are 28, 29 & 27 respectively & their [abundances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements) are similar it will be interesting when NASA reaches 16 Psyche. By the way, Fe has a density of 7.874 g/cm3 & an element number of 26, but a higher abundance.

Comment: @Fred - I would still expect some high Cu meteorite examples to have been found if "representative". If so exceptionally rare that we have none, then not representative. It will be interesting to see what Bennu samples reveal too.